# Objective C Video Player lots of errors

Tags: objective-c

So On the simulator It works all perfect. No errors, nothing
Now I want to put it on my iPod and I get some unknow errors and I dont't know how to fix them.

-I have the `MediaPlayer.framework` and it is included in my build

Here is the error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NAME/Desktop/XCode/PROJECT/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController viewDidLoad] in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController viewDidLoad] in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController viewDidLoad] in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController playbackFinished:] in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController viewDidLoad] in MoviePlayViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification", referenced from:
      -[MoviePlayViewController viewDidLoad] in MoviePlayViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone tell me what the error means and what I have to check? :)

Thanks

The only thing whcih is understandable for me is: unsupported file format.

Comment: Are you trying to bundle your own copy of the framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't find the `MediaPlayer.framework` I believe is the problem. You need to update your Library Header Search Path in the build settings. It is looking for it on your desktop I believe.

You may need to add it to your target, relink it, or just make sure its pointing in the correct place.